# How do I import specific columns from XLSX to an array (Laravel)?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I need to import a table into an array. And import not all cells, but only 2 columns.

For example, from

| A | B | C | D | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

to

```
[
    {
        'A' => 1,
        'F' => 5,
    },
    {
        'A' => 6,
        'F' => 10,
    }
]
```

app\Imports\PricesImport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;

class PricesImport implements ToArray
{
    use Importable;

    public function array(array $rows)
    {
        return array($rows[0], $rows[4]);
    }
}
```

And the call in the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Imports\PricesImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function import(Request $request) {
        $array = Excel::toArray(new PricesImport, $request->file('file'));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Tried this option, but it returns all columns, not 2 specific columns
app\Imports\PricesImport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;

class PricesImport implements ToArray
{
    use Importable;
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = [];
    }

    public function array(array $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $row = $row->toArray();
            $this->data[] = array('sku' => $row[0], 'price' => $row[4]);
        }
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a hint from [Patrick Brouwers](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/discussions/3111#discussioncomment-574113), this worked:
app\Imports\PricesImport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToArray;

class PricesImport implements ToArray
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = [];
    }
    public function array(array $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $this->data[] = array('sku' => $row[0], 'price' => $row[4]);
        }
    }

    public function getArray(): array
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

And the call in the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Imports\PricesImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function import(Request $request) {
        $import = new PricesImport;
        Excel::import($import, $request->file('file'));
        $array = $import->getArray();
    }
}
```